# Conditional Compilation not behaving correctly in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, conditional-compilation

I'm having trouble in a standard WinForms app with Conditional Compilation

I have 2 .csproj's that reference the same Program.cs file (They live in the same folder on disk too)

In Project1.csproj I have a conditional compilation symbol defined called CONDITION_1

In Project2.csproj I have a conditional compilation symbol defined called CONDITION_2

```
static void Main()
{
  #if CONDITION_1
    DoSomething();
  #elif CONDITION_2
    DoSomethingElse();
  #else
    DoAnotherThing();
  #endif
    ContinueDoingStuff();
}
```

These symbols are defined the project settings for "All Configurations". *In my debug environment everything works great.* However when I do a fresh checkout of source and build on my build machine I open up Project2.exe in my decompiler and I notice that my source is like this

```
static void Main()
{
    DoAnotherThing();
    ContinueDoingStuff();
}
```

If I open up the solution file in Visual Studio and do a regular **build** (No clean, no rebuild, no code changes)

I open up the exe and notice the correct decompiled source for Project2.exe...

```
static void Main()
{
    DoSomethingElse();
    ContinueDoingStuff();
}
```

Any ideas? Is there a possibility of conditional symbols not being set correctly at compile time?

Comment: You probably forgot to set these conditionals for the Release configuration.

Comment: The conditionals are set for "All Configurations". This includes "Release". However I double checked the .csproj and the symbols are defined. Also, if they weren't set, that still wouldn't explain the behavior where a simple build (in Release mode) creates a correctly compiled exe.

Comment: Can you reproduce this behavior with a simple project and upload it someplace for us to take a look?

Comment: When I manually checked the .csproj, I noticed the symbol wasn't defined for Release|AnyCPU, but it WAS defined for Release|x86. So I guess when you set symbols for "All Configurations" it doesn't mean "All Platforms" too. Glad I found that!

Answer (score 3):

Alright, Alright. I figured it out. I feel a little silly, but at the same time this would be easy to miss.

Here's an excerpt of my .csproj

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
<ResGenToolArchitecture>Managed32Bit</ResGenToolArchitecture>
<OutputPath>..\BinPC\Release\</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>CONDITION_2</DefineConstants>
<Optimize>false</Optimize>
<DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
<PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and here's the one for Release|AnyCPU

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
<ResGenToolArchitecture>Managed32Bit</ResGenToolArchitecture>
<DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
<Optimize>true</Optimize>
<OutputPath>..\BinPC\Release\</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
```

In Visual Studio, I had the **CONDITION_2** set for the x86 target platform, but not AnyCPU. This was true of **both** .csproj's. However, *The first csproj was building in Release|x86 mode by default, and the second was building in Release|AnyCPU (which didn't have the symbol defined as shown above)*

Long story short, lesson learned. Always always check your symbol definitions in the project.

1. Right click the .csproj file, click **properties**.
2. In the **build** tab, Select **All Configurations**, and **All Platforms**(<-- This is what I forgot)
3. Now define the conditional compilation symbol and it will get set for all configurations